# Recursively checking if value is in dictionary list

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have data in the format:

```
lsta = [[0,1], [0,2], [1,3], [2,4], [3,5], [4,6], [5,7], [7,9], [8,10], [8,11], [10,12], [11,13], [11,14], [12,15], [12,16], [6,17], [8,17]]
```

I am attempting to split the data into two lists based on whether they are connected, so I guess you could consider the data a graph.
Currently, I have a recursive function that will follow the data through in sequence `[0,1]` -> `[1,3]` -> `[3,5]` etc.

However, this breaks down when the numbering doesn't go in order; for example, 6, 17 and 8 are connected but due to the formatting of the original data this would be split into multiple lists. My intended solution for this is to perform a check after the following of a sequence is exhausted to see if the value is found anywhere else in the dictionary (not just the key), if so the function would continue to follow from that point. Unfortunately, I can't quite get it to work, advice appreciated.

Current code below, the 'check' function is currently the bit that doesn't do as intended.

```
from collections import defaultdict


def split(items):
    # create lookup
    lookup = defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in items:
        lookup[k].add(v)

    results = []
    while sum(map(len, lookup.values())):
        # get first element from remaining items
        first_k = min((k for k in lookup if len(lookup[k])))
        first = first_k, min(lookup[first_k])

        # follow that element
        results.append(follow(first, lookup))

    return results

def follow(item, lookup):
    item_k, item_v = item
    lookup[item_k].remove(item_v)

    result = [item]
    # loop through all follow-up items (if any)
    for next_item in sorted(lookup[item_v]):
        # recursively follow the follow-up item
        result.extend(follow((item_v, next_item), lookup))
        try:
            #check if v appears in v of another key
            result.extend(check((item_v, next_item), lookup))
        except KeyError:
            break
    return result

def check(item, lookup):
    itm_k, itm_v = item
    rsult = []

    if itm_v in lookup.values():
        #if it appears again, follow item
        rsult.extend(follow((itm_k, next_item), lookup))
    return rsult



def test(items):
    for x in split(items):
        print(x)


lsta = [
    [ 0, 1],  [ 0, 2],  [ 1, 3],  [ 2, 4],
    [ 3, 5],  [ 4, 6],  [ 5, 7],  [ 7, 9],
    [ 8, 10], [ 8, 11], [10, 12], [11, 13],
    [11, 14], [12, 15], [12, 16], [ 6, 17],
    [ 8, 17],
]

test(lsta)
```

Desired output would be:

```
results = ([[0,1], [1,3], [3,5], [5,7], [7,9]], [[0,2], [2,4], [4,6], [6,17], [8,17], [8,10], [8,11], [11,13], [11,14], [10,12], [12,15], [12,16]])
```

Comment: Your expected output contains [8,17], [8,10] which doesn't match the description gave?

Comment: I have edited your post to reformat the code. Please confirm that I have it correct - indentation is very important!

Comment: So at [6,17] it wouldn't find any keys starting with 6, so would look for elements that match the value, [8,17] , it would then not find any keys for 17 so would look for those matching the key of [8,17], 8, and then continue. Hopefully that clarifies somewhat.

Comment: Looks correct, thanks @AustinHastings

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want to sort your pairs into two sets (connected graphs) and if you encounter a pair which has no node in one of the sets already found you follow future pairs until you find a note which is in one of the sets?

Comment: That's correct, and more succinctly put.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you take a step back, and think of your problem in a different way. According to your question, you are trying to identify connected subgraphs within the `lsta` list of pairs. According to you, the graphs are *simply connected* - that is, (a,b) is the same as (b,a) with no sense of *directedness*.

Looking at the first two pairs, you have `0,1` and `0,2`. That produces a subgraph consisting of `{0,1,2}` since you don't really care which end is common. The `set` type will be the key to your solution. Instead of worrying about recursion, try managing the sets to get the result you want.

First, import collections and then make your default dict. You don't need to import defaultdict directly, since you're only going to type it one time, and this cleans things up a bit:

```
import collections

Subgraphs = collections.defaultdict(set)
```

Now let's add your initial test data. **Please Note:** There is a 'bug' here, in that the last pair (8,17) ties the subgraphs together into one. You probably don't want that.

```
lsta = [
    [ 0, 1],  [ 0, 2],  [ 1, 3],  [ 2, 4],
    [ 3, 5],  [ 4, 6],  [ 5, 7],  [ 7, 9],
    [ 8, 10], [ 8, 11], [10, 12], [11, 13],
    [11, 14], [12, 15], [12, 16], [ 6, 17],
    [ 8, 17],
]
```

Now let's initialize the sets. Each *node* (integer) will point to a set that it is connected to. Initially, nodes are connected only to themselves, so each key `K` will point to a set `{K}`.

```
for a,b in lsta:
    Subgraphs[a].add(a)
    Subgraphs[b].add(b)
```

Now let's merge the sets. Each pair `(a,b)` means that `a` and `b` are connected. That means that those two nodes should share the *same* node-set, since they are connected (through each other) to the union of all neighbors.

We assume that node A points to a set, and all the nodes in that set *also* point to the same set. (This is a bit of Python trickery. They're not *copies* of the same set, but actual *references* to the identical object in memory.) This means that updating the set can be done just one time, and it will effect all the members.

```
for a,b in lsta:
    seta = Subgraphs[a]
    setb = Subgraphs[b]
    others = setb - seta
    seta |= setb
    print("Processing (%d, %d): %s" % (a, b, seta))

    print("... updating: ", others)
    for o in others:
        Subgraphs[o] = seta
```

At this point, all the keys (nodes) in the `Subgraphs` dictionary should point to sets that contain all their reachable neighbors. We'll print the input and result data, and leave you to it.

```
print("\n***********")
print(lsta)
print(Subgraphs)
```

You might want to remove that last pair: [8,17]. Also, you probably want to *identify* the unique subgraphs. I don't know what you're doing with this code, but if you really need the subgraphs, you could make them into `frozenset` objects, which could then be added to a `set` to produce a distinct collection. Alternatively, you could just iterate the keys of the `Subgraphs` dict, merging sets into a `seen` set and skipping any keys that are already in `seen`.

Here is the output I get when I run it with the `lsta` data as-is:

```
Processing (0, 1): {0, 1}
... updating:  {1}
Processing (0, 2): {0, 1, 2}
... updating:  {2}
Processing (1, 3): {0, 1, 2, 3}
... updating:  {3}
Processing (2, 4): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
... updating:  {4}
Processing (3, 5): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
... updating:  {5}
Processing (4, 6): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
... updating:  {6}
Processing (5, 7): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
... updating:  {7}
Processing (7, 9): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}
... updating:  {9}
Processing (8, 10): {8, 10}
... updating:  {10}
Processing (8, 11): {8, 10, 11}
... updating:  {11}
Processing (10, 12): {8, 10, 11, 12}
... updating:  {12}
Processing (11, 13): {8, 10, 11, 12, 13}
... updating:  {13}
Processing (11, 14): {8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
... updating:  {14}
Processing (12, 15): {8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
... updating:  {15}
Processing (12, 16): {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
... updating:  {16}
Processing (6, 17): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}
... updating:  {17}
Processing (8, 17): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}
... updating:  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 17}

*********
LSTA:  [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 7], [7, 9], [8, 10], [8, 11], [10, 12], [11, 13], [11, 14], [12, 15], [12, 16], [6, 17], [8, 17]]
Subgraphs:  defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {0: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 1: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 2: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 3: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 4: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 5: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 6: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 7: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 8: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 9: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 10: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 11: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 12: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 13: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 14: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 15: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 16: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, 17: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}})
```

And here is the result when I remove the [8,17] pair from `lsta`:

```
Processing (0, 1): {0, 1}
... updating:  {1}
Processing (0, 2): {0, 1, 2}
... updating:  {2}
Processing (1, 3): {0, 1, 2, 3}
... updating:  {3}
Processing (2, 4): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
... updating:  {4}
Processing (3, 5): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
... updating:  {5}
Processing (4, 6): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
... updating:  {6}
Processing (5, 7): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
... updating:  {7}
Processing (7, 9): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}
... updating:  {9}
Processing (8, 10): {8, 10}
... updating:  {10}
Processing (8, 11): {8, 10, 11}
... updating:  {11}
Processing (10, 12): {8, 10, 11, 12}
... updating:  {12}
Processing (11, 13): {8, 10, 11, 12, 13}
... updating:  {13}
Processing (11, 14): {8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
... updating:  {14}
Processing (12, 15): {8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
... updating:  {15}
Processing (12, 16): {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
... updating:  {16}
Processing (6, 17): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}
... updating:  {17}

*********
LSTA:  [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 7], [7, 9], [8, 10], [8, 11], [10, 12], [11, 13], [11, 14], [12, 15], [12, 16], [6, 17]]
Subgraphs:  defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {0: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 1: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 2: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 3: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 4: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 5: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 6: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 7: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 8: {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 9: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}, 10: {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 11: {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 12: {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 13: {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 14: {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 15: {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 16: {16, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 17: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 9}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I think I should add some clarity, and perhaps reword the original question too. The actual end result of this algorithm would be to split one graph into two graphs at a given point. The graph that this data came from is this [graph](https://s29.postimg.org/nkt2p9507/image.png), if you'd look past the terrible quick job I did in paint. Hence my initial approach, although I am more than open to changing my direction (I'm very new to python, and programming in general).